# Typescript `super` implementation not providing the value

Tags: typescript, typescript-class

I am trying to print the `name` from `extended` class. But getting an error as : `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Employee'.`

```
class Person {
    #name:string;
    getName(){
        return this.#name;
    }
    constructor(name:string){
        this.#name = name;
    }
}

class Employee extends Person {

    #salary:number;
    constructor(name:string, salary:number = 0){
        super(name);
        this.#salary = salary;
    }
    async giveRaise(raise:number):Promise<void> {
        this.#salary += raise;
        await this.#storySalary;
    }

    pay():void {
        console.log(`¤ ${this.#salary} is paid to ${this.name}.`);
    }
    async #storySalary():Promise<void> {
        console.log(`Salary ¤ ${this.#salary} is stored for ${this.name}`);
    }
}

const NewEmployee = new Employee('Sha', 300);
console.log(NewEmployee.getName(), NewEmployee.pay())
```

[Live Demo](http://shorturl.at/bwzB8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#name:string;` means `name` is a private property, you cannot extend private variables.

What you might be looking for is `protected name: string`

```
class Person {
    protected name:string;
    getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    constructor(name:string){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```